# How to preset object variable in method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, parameters

An example:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

    def edit(self, name=self.name, password=self.password): <- ERROR
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
```

I want to edit to name or password of the object like that:

```
object.edit(password="New password")
```

The error that comes:

```
undefined variable "self"
```

I did it like that because then I can only edit one thing and the other thing is still the same.
Please help me! Is there an other way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your `edit` function to accept a dict of keyword arguments, so you can tell which were given and which were not.

```
def edit(self, **kwargs):
    if 'name' in kwargs:
        self.name = kwargs['name']
    if 'password' in kwargs:
        self.password = kwargs['password']
```

You can call it with `instance.edit(password='newpass')`,
and only the password will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def edit(self, name=self.name, password=self.password): <- ERROR
```

Where you set `name=self.name` you're setting a default value. `self` isn't available here as you're passing it in with the other values.

I'd leave off the defaults here - you can handle validation in the `edit` routine itself. i.e. just have:

```
def edit(self, name, password):
```

Comment: Because you're not inside the method yet. You're passing in the value to `self`, which means at that point `self is None`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an instance attribute as the default argument of a method - default arguments are evaluated at the method definition time, not upon calling it, and at that point Python has no clue what `self` means (because no instances were created yet).

You'll need to introduce some logic to check which argument has been passed on to the method or not. This is easiest using `None` values as the default argument:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

    def edit(self, name=None, password=None):
        if name is not None:
            self.name = name
        if password is not None:
            self.password = password
```

You can even use a ternary operator to introduce the logic in a single line, if you feel like that's more readable:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

    def edit(self, name=None, password=None):
        self.name = name if name is not None else self.name
        self.password = password if password is not None else self.password
```

Comment: Thanks That was really helpful